# Xamarin Strange exception in VS2015

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm Developing an APP wich communicate with BLE devices.
everything works fine so fare but when i switch multiple times from an activity i get an undebuggable exception:

> 01-26 09:06:43.040 I/Timeline( 7341): Timeline:
>   Activity_launch_request id:BLEAPPtime:710885426 Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object. System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Debugger.AD7DebugExceptionEvent..ctor(Thread
>   thread, String description) in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\2599\1390b70a\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\Debugging\MonoTools.Engine\AD7Events.cs:line
>   433 at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Debugger.ExceptionsAdapter.OnUnhandledException(Object
>   sender, TargetEventArgs args) in
>   C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\2599\1390b70a\source\XamarinVS\src\Core\VisualStudio\Debugging\MonoTools.Engine\ExceptionsAdapter.cs:line
>   67 at
>   Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerSession.OnTargetEvent(TargetEventArgs
>   args) at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleBreakEventSet(Event[]
>   es, Boolean dequeuing) at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.HandleEventSet(EventSet es) at
>   Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.EventHandler() Thread
>   finished: #6 The thread '' (0x6) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I don't know where it came from if i debug every single step is passing until my activity finished at the last code bracket then i get this
weird exception.

Does someone has any clue how to debug this?
or about this BUG.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38122

Comment: Seems like a bug in Xamarin to me. Can you post this in here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: Done not helping me at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours and days struggling i found the problem !
the problem was that my application took to long to execute hes task so i wrapped it up on a background task

```
new Task (() => 
{ 
   //Your code here... 

}).Start();
```

So keep in mind you need to wireup long executing tasks even if the take not that long !
`

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same issue here you can see the captures:

[FirstError screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCIDf.png)

[SecondError screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNR4l.png)

I strongly think that there is a bug with BLE classes and Xamarin.Android debugger.

It seems to me that if all the code I put in

> RangeNotifier_DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete/
>   MonitorNotifier_EnterRegionComplete and MonitorNotifier_ExitRegionComplete

is ok then there are no problems, but if there are null references or another fails I am getting this problem and the whole debug sistem it is stuck.

In my experience working with this technology in visual studio I can say that I can just follow DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete with the debug the first time then it goes it self and it does not stop anymore even if I can see clearly that the program continues.

I also notice that when it is not working properly I can put a breakpoint and the whole program is stuck in this point but I can not see the breakpoing in visual studio and sometimes this errors that I post came out.

My advice is:

1. First of all, check well that there are no null objects or problems in the code you are putting into this methods from the BLE libraries. **For example testing the functions outside first.**
2. **Delete always bin and obj folders after cleaning the solution as it is said in** [Breakpoints and Exceptions stopped working properly, xamarin android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987318/breakpoints-and-exceptions-stopped-working-properly-xamarin-android).
3. Let's wait for an update and pray we can finish the app we are doing anyway!!

I hope it helps because I am in the same situation and it sucks so much!

Comment: Thnx yes i hope i also made a bugzilla on Xamarin